# Issue with un-clicking radio button or changing button to checkbox

Tags: javascript, php

I'm having some issues making the radio button unclickable. as I've seen that we can use check-box's instead but even changing the

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">
        <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i> 
        <?php echo _UPDATE_WORK_ORDER_LANG_; ?> : 
        <b><?php echo WO_CODE.$data['IdProject']; ?>
    </h4>
</div>
<?php     
    if ($data['cus_failer_assign_form_name'] == "Customer_Failure_Symptoms_BCM") { ?>
        <div class="form-group" id="show" style="padding: 10px;">
            <h3>Fault Symptoms Report</h3>
            <form role="form" method="post" action="">
                <div class="box-footer">
                    <b>Customer Failure Symptoms Checklist: </b>
                    Brake Control Module (BCM);<br />
                    <span style="font-weight:normal!important;">
                        Please select each of the following failures based on the issues you are experiencing with your module:<br /><br />
                    </span>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="rad_1" id="rad_1" value="1" <?php if ($rad_1_date['rad_1'] == "1") { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?> />
                        <label>The ABS light is on</label>
                    </div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. What is the issue with using checkboxes?

Comment: i'm trying to change radio button to Checkbox or make it so that the radio button is un clickable.

Comment: Radio buttons cannot be "un-selected" by design. I would not change that behavior, because nobody would expect that. Either add an option "None" or go with checkboxes (and don't style them like radio buttons, because, again, terrible design).

Answer (score 0):

To make any input "unclickable" just add the "disabled" attribute:

`<input type="radio" name="myradio" disabled/> This is a disabled input`

To make it checked and disabled:

`<input type="radio" name="myradio" checked disabled/> This is a checked and disabled input`